# working ffmpeg command fails when using in nginx with rtmp module

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg

I have a tested code I did in a "bash" file. It works perfect on shell. I change only params to get it to work  with nginx rtmp module, but ffmpeg says always and understandable error. This is the code:

```
exec_push ffmpeg -re -y -i rtmp://localhost:1935/live/$name  \
                            -c:v libx264 -c:a aac  \
                            -g 24 -keyint_min 24   -preset veryfast -tune zerolatency -movflags +faststart -vsync passthrough  \
                            -filter_complex '[0:v]format=pix_fmts=yuv420p,split=3[in1][in2][in3];[in1]scale=320:-2[320x];[in2]scale=640:-2[HQ640x];[in3]scale=1280:-2[HD1280x];[0:a]aresample=44100[audio]'  \
                            -map '[320x]'       -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -crf 31 -maxrate 170k -bufsize 170k      -f mp4 rtmp://localhost:1935/rtmp_hls/$name_320x  \
                            -map '[HQ640x]'     -profile:v baseline -level 3.1 -crf 25 -maxrate 1000k -bufsize 1000k    -f mp4 rtmp://localhost:1935/rtmp_hls/$name_HQ640x  \
                            -map '[HD1280x]'    -profile:v main -level 3.1 -crf 19 -maxrate 4000k -bufsize 4000k        -f mp4 rtmp://localhost:1935/rtmp_hls/$name_HD1280x  \
                            -map '[audio]'      -b 128k                                                                 -f mp4 rtmp://localhost:1935/rtmp_hls/$name_audio 2>>/var/www/html/ffmpeg-live-output-$name.log;
```

And this is the error launched by mmpeg

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.4-1~bpo8+1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~bpo8+1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --disable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
[flv @ 0x55e430547740] video stream discovered after head already parsed
[flv @ 0x55e430547740] audio stream discovered after head already parsed
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://localhost:1935/live/directo':
  Metadata:
    Server          : NGINX RTMP (github.com/sergey-dryabzhinsky/nginx-rtmp-module)
    displayWidth    : 1280
    displayHeight   : 720
    fps             : 24
    profile         : 
    level           : 
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 26.023000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24.42 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn, 48 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp
[NULL @ 0x55e4305e0b40] Unable to find a suitable output format for '
'

: Invalid argument
```

Does anyone could help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for line breaks `\`. Nginx usess regular expressions to parse the configuration:

```
exec_push ffmpeg line 1
                 line 2
                  ...
                 line n;
```

Comment: You save my life!!! That solved one on the problems. However, now I have some other "errors" as you can read:

Comment: ... as you can read in the code above

`code`
[flv @ 0x560b916161a0] video stream discovered after head already parsed
[flv @ 0x560b916161a0] audio stream discovered after head already parsed
muxer does not support non seekable output
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argumentStream mapping:
`code`

Those mesages doesn't appear in the bash version, despite the stream source is in the same format (but one is saved in a mp4 file and the other is streamed thru rtmp).

Comment: @RafaelLinuxUser `-f flv`

Comment: I decided to not use "filter_complex" and correct the output to "flv" as aergistal said. Now it's working .... but ABR is doing something weird. But that should be other question. Thank you.